# How to get information from an xlsx file in Python?

Tags: python, import-from-excel

I have to create a mailing list of people belonging to a certain institution. The information is only available in .xlsx file. The columns of xlsx are as follows: institution, DOB, Program, ..., EmailID. How do I do this, instead of reading each entry myself and then typing the email into Google contacts?

I know I am asking a lot, especially since I have no idea how to operate Google sheets; like I am not sure if there is a way in Google sheets to do that. All I need are some directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read/write .xlsx files using openpyxl. Here is the link to the [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

You can read from the .xlsx as follows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('email_contacts.xlsx')
print wb2.get_sheet_names()
```

To add the details into Google Contacts you can use the Google Contacts API. Just read the official documentation on how to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The `openpyxl` mentioned in the other answer appears to be better.

The *easiest* method is to save the file in XLS format (97-2003 format) and then use the [XLRD](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) module to parse the file. To take care of files not already in this format, you can open the file in excel and then save into the correct format:

```
xlsx_files = glob.glob('*.xlsx') 

if len(xlsx_files) != 0:
    xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application') 

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    for file in xlsx_files: 
        xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)) 
        xlWb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file.split('.xlsx')[0] + 
    '.xls'), FileFormat=1) 
        xlWb.Close()

    for file in xlsx_files: 
        os.unlink(file)
```

To then access the sheet with xlrd:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
#First sheet:
sh = wb.sheet_by_name(wb.sheet_names()[0])
#Select a column, columns start at 0:
pl_id_column = sh.col_values(0)
#Iterate through the rows:
for rownum in range(12,sh.nrows):
    print pl_id_column[rownum]
```

Answer (score -1):

It is the easiest to run excel and save the 'xlsx' file as 'csv' file. Then it is all ASCII and easy to print out the one column 'EmailID' if that's the only column you want.

To add the details into Google Contacts you can use the Google Contacts API. Just read the official documentation on how to use the API.

Comment: If you don't intend to at least give a tiny overview of handling csv files in python, post this as a comment, not as an answer.